# How to add CSS in <li> tag

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I am trying to add customized padding for images within navbar on the right hand side in Bootstrap. I want to keep left/right padding for the left group at 15px (or whatever is by default in navbar) and right group at 4px.

```
    <style>
       li.custom { 
       padding-top: 14px;
       padding-left: 2px;
       padding-right: 2px;
       background-color: red;
      }
    </style> 

    <nav class="navbar">
    <!-- Navbar links left side  -->
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li>Link1</li>
        <li>Link2</li>
    </ul>


    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right"> 
        <li class="custom"><a href="#"><img style="height: 15px;"src="image1.jpg"></a></li>
        <li class="custom"><a href="#"><img style="height: 15px;"src="image2.jpg"></a></li>
    </ul>
    </nav>
```

If I override at nav level, it applies the changes to all items (on the left and right side). I also tried to assign custom class to items on the right side but it did not work. It kept the default padding.

I am expecting 4px padding at right side but the padding is still as default.

Comment: This code is working fine for me. You can see the fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/z7uh16be/). Is your `<style>` tag coming after you link to bootstrap? CSS sheets cascade, meaning that if you have your personal styling *before* the bootstrap styling, it will be overridden.

Comment: @Nick yes I have my personal CSS after I linked boostrap, same as you. This is horizontal menu but it is wrapped inside navbar. I updated the code with navbar which is using default values.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that you want to override other style definitions with your custom class, just put `!important` to it as below:

```
<style type="text/css">
       li.custom { 
       padding-top: 14px !important;
       padding-left: 2px;
       padding-right: 2px;
       background-color: red;
      }
</style>
```

Check JS Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/sov90tmb/)

*If you are using the css with a js framework like angular, try adding it to the module's style template file or consider modifying the style in the javascript.*

Comment: This is **NOT** how `!important` should be used, and this does not fix the problem.

Comment: @nick @ lan P it did not work. Still same default padding.

Comment: @Alex I updated my answer and added a JSFiddle link using bootsrap boilerplate, maybe you can play with that one

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply only on the right side. Take advantage of the `navbar-right` as part of your selector. Like this:

```
<style>
       .navbar-right > li { 
       padding-top: 14px;
       padding-left: 2px;
       padding-right: 2px;
       background-color: red;
      }
</style>
```

You don't need to create the custom class.

Comment: it did not work. Still same default padding in navbar.